# How to deallocate memory for char*

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc, free

I'm writing text rpg game and i want to, at the end, deallocate memory and the problem is with one char* it deallocates properly and with other char* i get game.exe has triggered a breakpoint error but i can't find how are those cases different.

```
skills *_skills;
_skills = (skills*)malloc(moj_konfig.skill_n * sizeof(skills));
for (int i = 0; i < moj_konfig.skill_n; i++)
{
    _skills[i].name = malloc(moj_konfig.ile_znakow * sizeof(char));

}

items **_it;
_it = (items**)malloc(moj_konfig.ekwipunek_wiersze * sizeof(items *));
if (_it == NULL) exit(1);
for (int i = 0; i < moj_konfig.ekwipunek_wiersze; i++)
{
    _it[i] = malloc(moj_konfig.ekwipunek_kolumny * sizeof(items));
    for (int j = 0; j < moj_konfig.ekwipunek_kolumny; j++)
    {
        _it[i][j].nazwa = malloc(moj_konfig.ile_znakow * sizeof(char));
    }
    if (_it[i] == NULL) exit(1);
}

quests *_quests;
_quests = (quests*)malloc(moj_konfig.ilosc_q * sizeof(quests));
for (int i = 0; i < moj_konfig.ilosc_q; i++)
{
    _quests[i].name = malloc(moj_konfig.ile_znakow * sizeof(char));
    _quests[i].done = 0;
    _quests[i].taken = 0;
}
```

it's in the function that returns struct type at the end

```
ret->it = _it;
ret->skill = _skills;
ret->quest = _quests;
return ret;
```

And the deallocation looks like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < moj_konfig.max_hero; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < moj_konfig.ekwipunek_wiersze; j++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < moj_konfig.ekwipunek_kolumny; z++)
        {
            free(heroes[i].it[j][z].nazwa);
        }
        free(heroes[i].it[j]);
    }
    free(heroes[i].it);

    for (int j = 0; j < moj_konfig.ilosc_q; j++)
    {
        free(heroes[i].quest[j].name);
    }
    free(heroes[i].quest);

    for (int j = 0; j < moj_konfig.skill_n; j++)
    {
        free(heroes[i].skill[j].name);
    }
    free(heroes[i].skill);

    free(heroes[i].name);
    free(heroes);
}
```

And i get error only when i free skills name and quests name but not when i free items name. (it is items)

EDIT:: I changed a few things and it still doesn't work with visual studio but when i tried it in code blocks it works just fine so maybe, just maybe it's some kind of vs problem

Comment: FYI, names starting with leading underscore are reserved and may lead to undefined behavior. And they are just ugly.

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I thought that is was just if the leading underscore was followed by an uppercase letter, or if the name contained two underscores that it is reserved. Still very ugly.

Comment: It is unclear what `moj_konfig.ile_znakow` is but did you forget to allow for the string terminator when allocating space for names?

Comment: @ThomasJager Reading the second bullet here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3p1 A bit obscure, so now you make me doubt.

Comment: moj_konfig.ile_znakow is just a int that sets how long the names can be (its 20)

Comment: Life is better without typedef's.  `struct skills * s = malloc( moj_konfig.skill_n * sizeof *s)` is readable.

Comment: What I meant is, should you be adding 1 for the string terminator? `_skills[i].name = malloc(moj_konfig.ile_znakow + 1);` A string of length `20` needs `21` bytes to store it.

Comment: @WeatherVane tried that but the problem stays, and besides like i said it works for items

Answer (score 0):

*heroes* does not appear in your code but `free(heroes);` must be replaced by `free(heroes[i]);` in your loop

*after* the loop may be `free(heroes);` must be done but only if it is a pointer you allocated

Comment: @TomaszGłowacki you do not give enough code to allow us to compile and execute or just check looking at ;-)

Comment: i mean the code is pretty long and i dunno how to cut it so you could compile it just for this problem

Comment: @TomaszGłowacki yes, I understand, but we are not extra lucid ^^ If you cannot take into account my remark and if you can execute your code under _valgrind_ to see your invalid memory access, or under a debugger